# How to search a certain column once you have the correct row in excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am looking to create a script that will automatically fill out customer shipping information into a web form (DPD). The order management system we use at work allows you to export order information into an excel spreadsheet and this includes the order number, billing and shipping address and some other information that is not to relevant.

I found a way to use xlwings to find a specifc phrase within excel. The desired use of this is to be able to enter an order number like "102" for example and then using .address I can get the cell location. I will post the draft code below:

```
import xlwings as xw

book = r'ord.xlsx'
sheet = 'Order Export 1'


def get_row(ordernum):

    wb = xw.Book(book)
    sht = wb.sheets[sheet]

    order = wb.sheets[sheet].api.UsedRange.Find(ordernum)

    print(order.address)

    return()

def main():
    ordernum = float(input('What is your oder num?'))
    order_row = get_row(ordernum)

main() 

## Output ## 
What is your oder num?250
$A$2
```

Now I need to navigate along this row to certain columns and find additional information such as post code, order price, address line 1, town, city. All I have is the location of the row and I don't know how to navigate / search within that row for a value that is within the 'post code' column.

I was also loooking at using xlrd and openpyxl but found the find function did the job I needed the quickest. If these would provide the further functionality I need I would of course considering using those instead... or both. Apologies for my possible naivety currently in the process of self teaching and you just can't know what you don't know.

I think once I have the data I can confidently use selenium to fill out the form and then I will have shipping labels that no longer need to be manually filled out.

One last note, I have tried to find similar topics and found lots on finding certain values within a cell but now how to navigate from a found row as I am asking.

Thanks in advance,
William

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(order.address)`

Comment: @stovfl apologies for overlooking this in the first place. I have now edited it to show the output of print(order.address)

Comment: Do `return order.split('$')[2]`. *" find ... such as post code,..."*: Did you kow the Column ID, e.g. `D2`=>`D`, beforehand? Or did you need to find it from the Header.

Comment: No but I would know how many rows there would be as I would decide how many orders I want to export the data for. The column placement does remain constant.

Comment: Build a Range: `range = 'A{0}H{0}'.format(order_row)` and loop `for v in .range(range):`

Comment: I will try to implement this although im not totally clear what the solution is that's being reconmended. I am very new sorry.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your attemp.